# Play downloaded video in xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Octane.Xam.VideoPlayer in my application to play video because this player play stream and .mp4 video.

Now i am trying to play download video with this player but video didn't play. Can any one suggest me that how i will play download video in offline mode

My local url is :
/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/GS01_1564.mp4.
I am passing this url in source.

Comment: Can you please show a sample of the code you are using and explain the problem in more detail? e.g. does it just show a black screen, or does it crash, or hang? And at what line of code does the problem occur?

Comment: It's show black screen. I just passed this url "/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/GS01_1564.mp4" in source of player and second try i converted this url in Uri format and passed to video source in both cases it is giving black screen